# Refresh Control Issue with custom cells - Swift 4 IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I am building an iOS app and I am trying to implement a pull-down refresh control on my project. The data is fetched correctly from an API and displayed on my table. But the problem rises when I do pull down to refresh. The following situations happen:

1. If I pull down for a long distance from the top, and the tableview.reloadData() function is called, the cells in the non-visible portion of the table come with the default tableview cells on top of them, overlapping...
2. if I pull down multiple times in quick succession the same issue happens.

I believe that it is because tableview.reloadData() is called multiple times in quick succession. But why are the default cells getting dequeued on top of my custom cells? Here is the section of code in the function to handle the pulldown:

```html
@objc func refreshFunc(){
        //let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if myRefreshControl.isRefreshing{
            readJson { (activities) in
                self.activities = activities
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.myRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

Changing the code to the code below seems to remove the error, but the problem is that now I need to pull down twice in order to get the results updated on the table:

```html
@objc func refreshFunc(){
            readJson { (activities) in
                self.activities = activities
                
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            self.myRefreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }
```

Please note that running the reloadData on the main thread gives the same result, I still need to pull down twice to update.

Comment: Calling on main thread solves?

Comment: No, it didn't, please check below

Answer (score 2):

Please try to give some delay before refresh table view may it resolve your problem.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayTime) { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope it works

Cheers :)

Comment: is the time in seconds?

Comment: Even when I add some time as suggested, if I drag for a certain distance I will have the issue of the overlapping cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData
}
```

Try this, always, if u want change UI you have to call on main thread

Comment: It still does not solve the issue. When I reproduced what I described above I got the same issue, I had also tried it before as well. If I call the same code inside a button, I do not have such issue, but calling it with the pull to refresh controller brings up this issue. I think it is because the table is being moved (by pull) when tableview.reloadData() is called. But I still do not know how to fix the issue